# Should I remove ProtectDisc Driver?

Tags: copy-protection

I have found `ProtectDisc Driver, Version 11` on list of installed programs. Is it unwanted software which tries to controls anything on my computer? Should I uninstall it?

Comment: A simple Google search reveals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protect_Software#ProtectDISC, http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/ProtectDisc-Driver-Version-11-9909-program.aspx - It's copy protection software.  If you want to uninstall it, go ahead, it's your computer.  :)

Comment: @techie007 I question unistalling this software because I don't know if I gain anything thanks to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's copy protection for a piece of software you have installed.

We don't know which software you have, or which one installed this as it's copy protection.

Since it's your computer, and your software, you have to decide (IMO) if you want to uninstall it or not.  You know it's intent, and that it's not malicious, since you went and read all about it at those links (right?).

Knowing that, if you legitimately own whatever software it's trying to protect, then why worry?  Just uninstall it.  If it turns out you need it in the future to make whatever program run, you can reinstall from your legitimate source.